# Script to set cell color to none if the cell text has a strikethrough?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, google-sheets-formula

Can anyone help with a script that will set the color of a cell in Google Sheets to none (or white if none is not possible) if the cell text has strikethrough applied?

Also note, the cell range I'm working with is O2:AF30 and my sheet will have rows added as time goes on.

I've tried using conditional formatting and that doesn't seem to be capable of this.

Answer (score 1):

script for detecting strikes:

```
function CHECKSTRIKE(reference) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var formula = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  var args = formula.match(/=\w+\((.*)\)/i);
  try {
    var range = sheet.getRange(args[1]);
  }
  catch(e) {
    throw new Error(args[1] + ' is not a valid range');
  }
  var lines = range.getFontLines();
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    output.push(lines[i].map(function(a) {return a == 'line-through';}));
  }
  return output;
}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I'm getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read property "1" from null."